# SetOptions not working in Firestore Flutter WEB

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

Checking out Flutter Web. Seems Firestore Flutter Web integration is not quite there yet. 
Tried to pass {merge: true} param:

```
webFirestore
    .collection("/users")
    .doc(uid)
    .set(map, {merge: true});
```

{merge: true} is underlined with red lines. Tried different formats, none working. 
Does anyone know how the syntax needs to look like?

This is what the firestore docs are saying:

```
/// An object to configure the [WriteBatch.set] behavior.
/// Pass [: {merge: true} :] to only replace the values specified in
/// the data argument. Fields omitted will remain untouched.
@anonymous
@JS()
abstract class SetOptions {
  /// Set to true to replace only the values from the new data.
  /// Fields omitted will remain untouched.
  external bool get merge;
  external set merge(bool v);
  external factory SetOptions({bool merge});
}
```

Comment: Try it without the brackets.

Comment: Like that: .set(map, merge: true);?
Not working says named parameter merge is not defined

Comment: Are you using this [firebase](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase) package? The `cloud_firestore` package does not support Flutter for the web.

Comment: I'm using 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as WebFirebase; 'package:firebase/firestore.dart' as WebFirestore; - [this] (https://medium.com/multiverse-software/firebase-on-flutter-mobile-and-web-284812056c5c) workaround

Comment: You mentioned that it's underlined with red lines when you used brackets, what's the error?

Comment: Also, is it possible it's `options: {merge: true}`?

Comment: Nope, says it's undefined.

Comment: What's the error when you use the brackets?

Comment: This is a known issue. There is no SetOptions class for Flutter as yet.
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1212

Answer (score 16):

Was having the same issue, I believe this works:

```
webFirestore
    .collection("/users")
    .doc(uid)
    .set(map, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work

```
firestoreInstance.collection("users").doc(firebaseUser.uid).set(
  {
   "username" : "userX",
  },SetOptions(merge: true))
```

thank you